# comprehensive list of keys bindings for IdeaVim (PhpStorm vim emulator)

Tags: key-bindings, ide

I’m looking for comprehensive list of keys bindings for IdeaVim (vim emulator for PhpStorm and stuff like that). It looks like this plugin has lots of useful key binding which don’t exist in vim and aren’t standard.
I’ve this http://ideavim.sourceforge.net/vim/index.html . However it’is 10 years old and yet this is exactly the place where I found useful staff which still works.
Is there anything more actual?

Comment: The [README](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim) links to https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/src/com/maddyhome/idea/vim/package-info.java

Comment: Thanks, I read it. This list isn't complete. That why I've come here. Since guys from JetBrains don't like to talk.

Comment: the question is still actual

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about vi or Vim, but PHP Storm. See: https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/51

Answer (score 6):

The documentation does suck. I have no idea why they would leave it languishing so much.

Other than the links already posted, the other command to be aware of is `:actionlist` which will list all of the action commands you can map. I've also found it useful to search Github for 'ideavimrc' to see what others are doing.